# how to compile reactjs application by using gradle?

Tags: reactjs, gradle

Pl explain reactjs web application by using gradle to compile and generate .clases ?
Is it possible are not?if it is possible let me give example?

Comment: You realize ReactJS is a Javascript library and Gradle a Java build tool?

Comment: Are you talking about React Native perhaps? Is this for a web or Android project?